# how can i use search dropdown list in Titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I want to use a drop down list with text box searching ability. I am new to titanium, if anyone knows how then please inform me.

```
var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
    bottom : 60,
    width : 150
});
var data = [];
data.push(Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({
    title : 'Bananas'
}));
data.push(Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({
    title : 'Strawberries'
}));
data.push(Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({
    title : 'Mangos'
}));
data.push(Titanium.UI.createPickerRow({
    title : 'Grapes'
}));
picker.add(data);
win1.add(picker);
var button = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title : 'Login',
    right : 50,
    bottom : 30,
    width : 80,
    height : 60
});

win1.add(button);
```

Comment: You made a picker, not a list, is this intentional?

Comment: what is "searching ability"?

Comment: I guess he just wanted something like [jQuery auto complete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox) in his app